# Do i need to synchronize?

Tags: java, user-interface, synchronization

Do I need to add some kind of synchronization? I create another thread to manage the TCP communication with a server. The flow is this:

```
private void sendLetterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
try {
// TODO add your handling code here:
   session.getCurrentMatch().guessALetter(this.letterTextField.getText());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please insert one letter only");
}}

public void guessALetter(String l) throws Exception {
    DataPacket dp = new DataPacket();
    Communicator c = new Communicator(p, session);
    c.start();
}

public class Communicator extends Thread {

private Packet packet;
private Session session;

public Communicator(Packet p, Session s) {
    this.session = s;
    this.packet = p;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Communicator: "+Thread.currentThread());
    Socket socket = session.getClientSocket();
    ObjectOutputStream out = session.getOut();
    ObjectInputStream in = session.getIn();

    ResponsePacket reply;


    try {

        out.writeObject(this.packet);
        out.flush();

        reply = (ResponsePacket) in.readObject();
        System.out.println("Received" + reply.getCurrentWordView() + reply.getCurrentWordView());

        session.getCurrentMatch().setLastReply(reply);

        session.getCurrentMatch().manageResponsePacket(reply);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Communicator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Communicator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{

    }}}

public void manageResponsePacket(ResponsePacket reply) {

    this.setLastReply(reply);

    if (reply.isGameMode()) {
        setWordView(reply.getCurrentWordView());
        setCounter(reply.getFailedAttemptsCounter());

        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(EventEnum.GAMERESPONSE);
    } else if (reply.isGameOverMode()) {
    }
}
```

So as you can see the second thread is the one that updates the gui.

Comment: in the method "guessALetter", a new thread is started

Comment: but the main thread is another one, right?

Comment: k, so you have the main app thread calling the other methods?  no other threads?  is the main thread, the EDT?  (is this a swing/awt app)?

Comment: it is a swing app, so the main should be the edt. I have created no other threads

Comment: -1 and voting to close as too localized.  What problem are you having?  Can you break down you question into something that isn't just a code dump?  I'm not sure how this question would be helpful for anyone else as it's too broad.

Answer (score 1):

if `manageResponsePacket()` updates the swing/awt GUI, you have a problem.  you can only update a swing/awt GUI on the EDT.  use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to update the GUI with the ResponsePacket.

Comment: well, I actually use the observer pattern, so I just call notifyObservers from that method. Is that a problem?

Comment: is notifyObservers synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: I use the one provided by java (implementing and extending Observable and Observer), so I don't know how it is implemented.

Comment: it is synchronous, so, my answer still stands as is.